# On the inequality $\left(\frac{R_{n+1}}{R_n}\right)^n<n^{\frac{5}{4}}(\log n)^3$ for Ramanujan primes

Tags: number-theory, inequality, prime-numbers, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

The Wikipedia *Firoozbakht's conjecture* refers (see also the comments of [OEIS *A182514*](https://oeis.org/search?q=A182514)) an inequality due to Nicholson, I wondered if it is possible to prove the following conjecture.

**Conjecture.** *The Ramanujan primes* $R_n$ *satisfy* $$\left(\frac{R_{n+1}}{R_n}\right)^n<n^{5/4}(\log n)^3$$ *for all integer* $n>2$.

The corresponding Wikipedia for Ramanujan primes is [*this*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_prime). My attempt of proof using the inequalities that I know was failed. I've tested the conjecture for the first few thousand of Ramanujan primes.

> **Question.** Can you prove or refute previous conjecture? I'm asking for hints to prove it, or well feedback about its veracity: let's say what work can be done about it. **Many thanks.**

I've considered right add here one of those references from previous articles of Wikipedia.

### References:

[1] Jonathan Sondow, *Ramanujan primes and Bertrand's postulate*, Amer. Math. Monthly, 116 (7), (2009), pp. 630–635.

Comment: In this post I tried to create the best (the most sharp) variant of Nicholson inequality, now for Ramanujan  primes $R_n$, of the form $$\left(\frac{R_{n+1}}{R_n}\right)^{\gamma\cdot  n}<n^{\alpha}(\log n)^\beta$$ for positive reals $\alpha,\beta$ and $\gamma$, to be true for all integers $n>n_0$ for a suitable (and small) positive integer $n_0$.

Comment: I think that it is reasonable that after ends/expires the bounty if there is some helpful answer, since I am asking about what work can be done about the veracity of the conjecture I should consider accept an answer.

Comment: What is your motivation for such a conjecture? Beyond just the wikipedia pages you link, why do you think this should be true? What are the motivations/consequences?

Comment: Many thanks for your attention/questions @RomainS . If I remember well 1) I did a few experiments with a Pari/GP script from which I didn't find a counterexample, 2) the arithmetic function that counts Ramanujan primes $\leq x$ is similar than $\pi(x)$ (I know it from the literature), 3) I tried to evoke a similar inequality for Ramanujan primes than Nicholson's inequality. I don't know consequences for my conjecture but I think that the world of Ramanujan primes is interesting (and it includes applications in technology).

Comment: With this my account, on MathOverflow I've asked for example the question with identificator **351902** and title *A conjecture about an inequality that involve Ramanujan primes* (this was downvoted, I say it with respect to MO users, but I feel that is very interesting). I add this comment if you want to read the post, isn't required a response @RomainS . I've edited other posts about Ramanujan primes on Mathematics Stack Exchange and MathOverflow.

Comment: In my (admittedly limited) experience, this kind of question tends to be quite hard to prove. Furthermore, as I understand it, bounds like these seem to arise as a result of a new techniques or ideas; I don't think it is very common for mathematicians to start with such a conjecture and work backwards. With this in mind, perhaps try to translate your numerical computations into an intuition about what's really going on, what underlying structure is being revealed, rather than a conjecture with seemingly arbitrary bounds. That will likely lead you to something interesting!

Answer (score 1):

This answer ought to be understood in conjunction with the comments I have made on the above post: I am by no means an expert, but a conjecture like this, with no motivation or reason to exist, seems odd. Nevertheless, this conjecture is most likely true. With $P_n$ denoting the $n^{th}$ prime, we have  $P_{2n}<R_n<P_{4n}$ and, more interestingly, $R_n\sim P_{2n} $ as $n\to \infty$ (see OEIS or [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0907.5232.pdf0)). With this in mind, we can apply the prime number theorem to estimate
$$R_n\sim 2n\log(2n),$$
hence
$$\Big{(}\frac{R_{n+1}}{R_n}\Big{)}^n\sim\Big{(}\frac{2(n+1)\log(2(n+1)}{2n\log(2n)}\Big{)}^n.$$
As $n\to \infty$, this tends to $e$. It follows that the left hand side of the given conjecture therefore tends itself to a constant, and the result follows (trivially).

For fun, here is some Mathematica code, and a few graphs:

```
RamanujanPrime[n_] := 1 + Select[Range[4*n*Log[4 n]], PrimePi[#] - PrimePi[#/2] == n - 1 &]]//Max
RPApprox[n_, const_: 2] := const*n*(Log[const*n])
```

To see how good this approximation is, we run

```
DiscretePlot[{RPApprox[n], RamanujanPrime[n]}, {n, 1, 100}]
```

and obtain this:
[image]
To see OP's conjecture in action, we run

```
DiscretePlot[{(RamanujanPrime[n + 1]/RamanujanPrime[n])^n, n^(5/4)*Log[n]^3}, {n, 1, 100}]
```

(this could be made much slicker without recomputing the list, but oh well), and obtain this:
[image]
Often, it is not the answer itself that is interesting, but rather *why* the question was asked, and *how* the answer is obtained. It is worth keeping that in mind!

Comment: Many thanks for your excellent contribution. Compare your reasoning, as you said the prime number theorem and again this limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{(n+1)\log(n+1)}{n\log(n)}\right)^n$ and Nicholson's inequality (stronger form) from the Wikipedia's article *Firoozbakht's conjecture*. Regarding your question of *why* I was asking these type of questions that I tried to be honest (expressing what I think about some problems in mathematics) more than once in these Mathematics Stack Exchange and MathOverflow sites.